# Navigate through jsfiddle commits?

Tags: jsfiddle

I try to go to a previous commit in jsFiddle and can't find anything that could get me where i want. 
Is Someone that knows better jsFiddle and would like to share some tips? Thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In jsFiddle the versions are Found by their change number.   So for example, if you go to http://jsfiddle.net/uuvpZ/ then you will see the code as it was originally created.   However if you go to [http://jsfiddle.net/uuvpZ/1](http://jsfiddle.net/uuvpZ/1/)  you will see the next change that was saved or version #1.    So you can see any modifications by added the change number to the URL.

```
 Original 
 http://jsfiddle.net/uuvpZ/

 modified version #1
 http://jsfiddle.net/uuvpZ/1
```